# Uploading files to external services with Guzzle and SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe, guzzle

We have a requirement of uploading multiple files to an external files bucket via an end-point of that external service. We are going to send the uploaded files to the service immediately once the 'Upload' button pressed instead of saving the files within SilverStripe CMS.

Do we need to serialize the files first and then send the strings or we can send the files directly?

We are using SilverStripe and Guzzle in our project.

Cheers

Comment: Which version of SilverStripe are you using? Questions like this might be better suited to the [SilverStripe forums](https://forums.silverstripe.org), which are more for general questions. StackOverflow is for specific code questions =)

Comment: Hi Robbie, it's SilverStripe 3.1. actually we are working on a CWP instance.

Comment: When you say "external files bucket" are you talking about S3?

Comment: Not really, we have a file bucket built on Open Text platform.